# Searchable Entry ExpressionEngine

Tags: php, sql, expressionengine

to set some custom field entry searchable i need go to channel field manager and set it manually. Have some way to set ALL fields searchable? Sql query? or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds very unnecessary. However if you're wanting to do it you could run a basic update query on exp_channel_fields.

```
UPDATE `exp_channel_fields` SET `field_search` = "y"
```

I have not tested this... but for basic fields it should have you covered.